# Generalization of Farkas' Lemma to Hermitian Matrices

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, linear-programming, semidefinite-programming

I recently stumbled upon a well-known version of Farkas' Lemma which, roughly speaking, I would like to generalize from real vectors to hermitian matrices, as it seems promising for something else I am currently working on. To be precise, the version of Farkas' Lemma I am interested in is the following:

> **Lemma.** Let $m,n\in\mathbb N$, $B\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and $b\in\mathbb R^m$. The following statements are equivalent.
>
> (a) There exists $y\in\mathbb R^n$, $y\geq 0$ such that $By\leq b$.
>
> (b) For all $x\in\mathbb R^m$, $x\geq 0$ together with $x^TB\geq 0$ implies $x^Tb\geq 0$.

In the following, consider $\operatorname{pos}(k)\subset\operatorname{Her}(k)\subset\mathbb C^{k\times k}$ with $\operatorname{Her}(k)$ the real-linear subspace of all hermitian $k\times k$ matrices and $\operatorname{pos}(k)$ the cone of all positive semi-definite $k\times k$ matrices. Then $\leq$ changes from entrywise positivity of vectors to the partial order on $\operatorname{Her}(k)$ induced by positive semi-definiteness.

> **Farkas' Lemma (possible generalization)**. Let $m,n\in\mathbb N$, an $\mathbb R$-linear function $\Phi:\operatorname{Her}(n)\to\operatorname{Her}(m)$  and $B\in\operatorname{Her}(m)$ be given. The following statements are equivalent.
>
> (a) There exists $Y\in\operatorname{pos}(n)$ such that $\Phi(Y)\leq B$.
>
> (b) For all $X\in\operatorname{pos}(m)$ such that $\operatorname{tr}(X\Phi(Z))\geq 0$ for all $Z\in \operatorname{pos}(n)$ one has $\operatorname{tr}(XB)\geq 0$.

While this does not seem super difficult, I would like to know if the result I am looking for (or some version of it) is maybe already known in the literature, so I could just cite and use it---hence the tag **[reference-request]**. I did search the net for a bit but linear programming and SDP are anything but my main field (which is closer to functional analysis and operator theory) so any pointers or hints regarding literature as well as any counter-examples are appreciated!

Also I hope that the tags for this question (or rather request) are appropriate. If this is not the case, feel free to let me know. Thank you in advance!

**Edit** *(2019/08/19)*: I just proved the generalization stated above (mostly analogous to the vector case, as elaborated in the comments). Still, my request goes on because citing something here would be nicer---after all the one-and-a-half pages of proof do not really fit (thematically) into the manuscript in question.

Comment: How about Lemma 12.10 in https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15859-f11/www/notes/lecture12.pdf  ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I also found these lecture notes but the problem I want to apply the generlized lemma to something of the form mentioned above (find a solution $Y\geq 0$ to $\Phi(Y)\leq B$ with non-trivial $\Phi$); is there an obvious connection between this and Lemma 12.10 because as an outsider these don't seem related?

Comment: The way to understand how Lemma 12.10 is a generalisation of the usual Farkas lemma is to consider the case of all $A_i$ being diagonal. Pehaps it's not the right generalisation for you. It puzzles me in your formulation that your $\Phi$ appears to be more general than usually looked at in the SDP setting.

Comment: I see what you mean now, thanks! Actually I just proved the claimed generaliztion (or so I hope), mostly analogous to the proof in the vector case (one shows the related result that $By=b$ has a positive solution iff "for all $x\in\mathbb R^m$ ...", and then shows $By\leq b$ has a positive solution iff $(I_m\ B)y'=b$ has a positive solution to connect the $\leq$ with the $=$ case). Still, having something to cite here would be nicer because the one-and-a-half pages of proof do not really fit (thematically) into the manuscript in question.